# method `actionPerformed()` getting executed several times(more than countable)

Tags: java, swing, event-dispatch-thread

```
while(b==true){
    if((!tf.getText().equals("")) ){
        System.out.println("outside actionPerformed");
        p.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){     
                System.out.println("Hello");                
                ne.remove(p);
                ne.revalidate();
                ne.repaint();
                System.out.println("why"+EventQueue.isDispatchThread()); 
                b=false;
                System.out.println(b); 
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Whatever is inside `actionPerformed()` is being executed several times. It is supposed to be executed only once.

Comment: It's hard to tell with that formatting job.

Comment: You're adding the actionlistener inside a loop, no wonder it's getting executed multiple times.

Comment: Each time your `if` condition is true, you register a new listener, so you end up with a bunch of  registered `ActionListener` objects.

Comment: @Berger    But I clicked the button only once.

Comment: Everytime the loop runs, it's adding a new `ActionListener` to `p`...as I said last time, this is not how you should be using a GUI, you don't need these loops and instead should be reacting to the GUI events as they arise

Comment: @Mathews Mathai : Yes, but each  click will call ALL registered `ActionListener` objects, and you have registered many of them  .

Comment: @MadProgrammer How do I do that efficiently? I created a new thread but then that is giving rise to new problems.

Comment: You're thinking in to a linear fashion, GUIs are event driven, something might happen at some point in time, at which time you respond to it.  Swing is also not thread safe, so you're running the risk of race conditions. The answer will depend on what it is you're trying to achieve from the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Step 1.

Get rid of your threads, you don't need, in fact, thread's in Swing a dangerous and need to be treated very carefully

## Step 2.

You're thinking in to a linear fashion, this is not how GUIs work, GUIs are event driven, that is, something might happen in the future and you need to respond to it accordingly

For example, let's assume `p` is a `JButton`, you might have them declared as instance fields within your class...

```
private JButton p;
private JTextField tf;
```

Then when you initialise the UI (probably in the constructor), you would set up `p` and register it's `ActionListener`....

```
p = new JButton("Go");
p.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Hello");
        ne.remove(p);
        ne.revalidate();
        ne.repaint();
        System.out.println("why" + EventQueue.isDispatchThread());
        b = false;
        System.out.println(b);
    }
});
p.setEnabled(false);
```

Setting `p` disabled will prevent the user from clicking it.  This is good for two reasons, one it prevents the `ActionListener` from been triggered, but also, it sends a clear message to the user that they can't click this button. As far as I know, currently your button could be clicked, but perform no action...kind of frustrating to the user

Then you set up the text field...

```
tf = new JTextField(20);
tf.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {

    protected void update() {
        p.setEnabled(tf.getText().trim().length() > 0);
    }

    @Override
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        update();
    }

    @Override
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        update();
    }

    @Override
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        update();
    }
});
```

The `DocumentListener` in this case allows you to monitor for changes to the text fields state in real time and update the state of the button accordingly...

Comment: What is the diff between `DocumentListener` and `ActionListener` ?

Comment: Start by having a look at [How to Use Actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) and [Implementing a Document Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter). `ActionListener` is a generalised event which denotes that some "action" took place (ie the user pressed the [Enter] key on the text field) where as the `DocumentListener` is a focused listener, responsible for providing event notifications when a `Document` is modified in some way. In this case, the `DocumentListener` will be notified each time you type a key

Comment: That means, `DocumentListener` records live changes and doesn't need a button or key to trigger it. right?

Comment: @MathewsMathai Yes, more or less. It will also notify you when the OP cuts or pastes text into the field or the field is programically modified, which something like `KeyListener` won't

Comment: Okay. What happens if I there is no actionListener associated with a text field? In this case, does the `DocumentListener` come to rescue?

Comment: Yes and no, it won't tell you when the user presses the [Enter] key

Comment: But, it will record the change. right?

Comment: The `DocumentListener`, yes, it's independent of any other listeners (with the exception of the `DocumentFilter`, but that's beyond the current scope)

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Talking on your code;  and added

> if(p.getActionListeners().length==0){ //this line fix adding multiple
>   times

```
    while(b==true){ //loops multiple times and add multiple actionlistener and dangerous because of you CPU will be top while this loops run :)
        if((!tf.getText().equals("")) ){
            System.out.println("outside actionPerformed");
            if(p.getActionListeners().length==0){ //this line fix adding multiple times
                p.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){     
                        System.out.println("Hello");                
                        ne.remove(p);
                        ne.revalidate();
                        ne.repaint();
                        System.out.println("why"+EventQueue.isDispatchThread()); 
                        b=false; //This line execute when an action occurs
                        System.out.println(b); 
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What happens if `p` has other `ActionListener`s already registered to it (other than the one the OP is trying to add)?

Comment: this is the case :) I hope, questioner will understand this. And in reality this type of code is really buggy and not acceptable code.

Comment: *"and not acceptable code"* - So as professionals on a professional forum, perhaps we should be looking to suggest more acceptable and robust solutions. At least you'll know why if it attracts downvotes. *"I hope, questioner will understand this."* - Based on the OP's current approach, I doubt that they will :P

Comment: Does `getActionListener()` return an array of action listeners associated with `p` ?

Comment: Okay. In this case, this should work, because I have only one action listener associated with it.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I only try to help someone, but yes your answer is the best, now is it ok?

Comment: And I'm only trying to help two people, you and the OP

Comment: @YusufKARTAL Thanks for the help.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Peace out..Please.